# Eliminar dos caracteres de una frase

Tags: c, string

Hola me podrían ayudar tengo un problema con mi código me va bien cuando quiero eliminar un caracter pero si quiero eliminar dos o mas caracteres solo eliminar el primer caracter ingresado.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "funcion.h"
#include <string.h>
#define M 50
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char gtr[M];
    char gtres[M];
    char list[10];
    int i,j;
    printf("\nIngrese una frase: ");
    gets(gtr);
    printf("\nIngrese el caracter que desea eliminar: ");
    gets(list);
    i=0;
    j=0;
    while(gtr[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(list[0]!=gtr[i])
        {
            gtres[j]=gtr[i];
                j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    gtres[j]='\0';
    printf("\nFrase resultante es: %s ",gtres);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto imagen como se puede observar solo se elimina la `x` y no las dos `xz`.

Answer (score 0):

La comparación `list[0]!=gtr[i]` solo tiene en cuenta el primer caracter de `list`, o sea la "x".

Supongo que de lo que trata tu bucle es de copiar caracteres saltándose los que estén en `list`, por lo que esa comparación debería ser algo del estilo `(list[0]!=gtr[i]) && (list[1]!=gtr[i])`, para el caso en que `list` tenga dos caracteres.

De forma más genérica quizás deberías hacer una función `esta_en_lista(char, list)` que reciba el caracter que se está procesando (`gtr[i]`) y la lista de caracteres a borrar, y te retorne TRUE si `char` está en la lista, o FALSE si no.  Para lograr esto esa función debe iterar.

Por ejemplo podría estar implementada así:

```
int esta_en_lista(char ch, char* lista){
  for (int i=0; i<strlen(lista); i++) {
    if (ch == lista[i]) return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Gracias a esta función el `if` de tu bucle queda bastante sencillo:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char gtr[M];
    char gtres[M];
    char list[10];
    int i,j;
    printf("\nIngrese una frase: ");
    gets(gtr);
    printf("\nIngrese el caracter que desea eliminar: ");
    gets(list);
    i=0;
    j=0;
    while(gtr[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(!esta_en_lista(gtr[i], list))   // <<----- Aqui
        {
            gtres[j]=gtr[i];
                j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    gtres[j]='\0';
    printf("\nFrase resultante es: %s ",gtres);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Demo**

```
Ingrese una frase: Esto es una prueba

Ingrese el caracter que desea eliminar: aeo

Frase resultante es: Est s un prub
```